# Activation of Network Connection Failed

Tags: ubuntu, kali-linux, internet, zorin

Before installing routersploit on my zorin os, my wifi connection was connecting with home network. However when starting routersploit, suddenly the wifi I was connected to says "Activation of Network Connection Failed". After this incident I've been unable to connect to my wifi.

However, when I connect to my smartphone WiFi hotspot, the laptop gets connected without any issues.

The error happened after I installed routersploit. i believe it changed or modified some network settings which I'm unaware of. I tried: disabling IPv6 following this guide : [Fix: activation of network connection failed on Linux – Its Linux FOSS](https://itslinuxfoss.com/activation-of-network-connection-failed/#3) as well as this guide: [Fix: Activation of Network Connection Failed in Linux](https://appuals.com/activation-of-network-connection-failed-in-linux/) but none of them worked. Plz some-one help me get out of this mess.

output of IP a

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:1d:48:df:35:10 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp9s0
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 48:5a:b6:c5:04:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp8s0f0
    inet 192.168.43.245/24 brd 192.168.43.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo1
       valid_lft 2407sec preferred_lft 2407sec
    inet6 2409:4081:2e16:416:7a45:2eea:68d3:6c4/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 3407sec preferred_lft 3407sec
    inet6 2409:4081:2e16:416:d9f2:f19a:c714:a91a/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 3407sec preferred_lft 3407sec
    inet6 fe80::6c2a:931e:964:86f2/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Please add the output of `ip a` command.

Comment: @GAD3R sir, have added the output in the question please help.

Comment: yes @GAD3R sir, did the changes but have sent the router to check for repairs will test connecting again once router arrives.

However, one question I have is, if the problem was due to monitor mode then my mobile hotspot should not get connected also. But this is not the case I'm able to connect with my smartphone hotspot but not with the router WIFI, do you have any insight for this, I wanted to know why this is happening.

Comment: @GAD3R it was the correct solution, please add it again so that I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exit the monitor mode:

```
sudo ip link set wlo1 down
sudo iw wlo1 set type managed
sudo ip link set wlo1 up
```

Comment: it says cannot find a device WIFI_INTERFACE